# Is an application that uses Spring Http Invoker at risk from the the Java serialisation exploit?

Tags: java, spring, security

I have an application that exposes an endpoint using `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` from Spring. I have been trying to investigate whether or not this is at risk from the Java (Apache commons-collections) serialisation exploit (as detailed [here](http://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/)).

I have been trying to generate payloads that can be sent to the endpoint for testing, but I haven't managed to get a definitive answer so far. I have checked out the [ysoserial](https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial) project for generating payloads but I believe the problem with this is that the HttpInvoker expects the serialised Object to be of type `RemoteInvocation`, which is not what `ysoserial` generates.

So my questions are:

1. Is a Spring endpoint configured like this at risk?
2. How can I generate a payload that would exploit it, so that I can validate that I have closed the exploit after my fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own questions:

1. Yes. I have successfully managed to exploit my server using a simple http post to the Spring endpoint.
2. Spring Http Invoker expects the object it receives to be a `RemoteInvocation` instance, which contains a method to be executed on the server side (i.e. a method that you are exposing on some interface). It has the following constructor:

   public RemoteInvocation(String methodName, Class[] parameterTypes, Object[] arguments)

so to use the exploit you just have to put the object that ysoserial generates into the `Object[]` arguments. This will result in it being unserialised before attempting and failing to execute the method on the exposed interface and therefore it will execute the command you specified.